# Share button not working on app

Tags: android

I am trying to put a share button in my action bar, and it crashes whenever I try to launch the app.

My error is below:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This is not supported, use MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider()
                                                                             at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getActionProvider(MenuItemImpl.java:644)
                                                                             at com.example.install.factapp.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:42)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2646)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:298)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:85)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:241)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.preparePanel(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1273)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.doInvalidatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1553)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.access$100(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:89)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7$1.run(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:129)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/shareButton"
        android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider"
        android:title="@string/app_name"
        android:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

And here is the main activity with everything, including imports so I can diagnose my probel:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView factBox;
    TextView factNumberBox;
    FactNumbers numbersHolder = new FactNumbers();
    Facts factHolder = new Facts();
    Backgrounds backs = new Backgrounds();
    LinearLayout bg;
    Animation scaleIn;
    Animation slideOut;
    private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        factBox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.factTextBox);
        factNumberBox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numberBox);
        bg = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.background);
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menu.findItem(R.id.shareButton).getActionProvider();
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultShareIntent());

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }

    private Intent getDefaultShareIntent(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "SUBJECT");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Extra Text");
        return intent;
    }

    public void genFact(View view) {
        factBox.setText(factHolder.nextFact());
        factNumberBox.setText(numbersHolder.nextFactNumbers());
        slideOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slideout);
        factBox.startAnimation(slideOut);
    }

    public void previousFact(View view) {
        factBox.setText(factHolder.previousFact());
        factNumberBox.setText(numbersHolder.previousFactNumbers());
        scaleIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slidein);
        factBox.startAnimation(scaleIn);
    }

    public void randomButton(View view) {
        factBox.setText(factHolder.randomButton());
        factNumberBox.setText(factHolder.randomNumber());
    }


}
```

Comment: I suggest that you edit your question, posting the full stack trace and the full activity that has this `onCreateOptionsMenu()` code in it. This feels like you may be mixing two different action bar implementations (native and `appcompat-v7`).

Comment: @CommonsWare Just edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `AppCompatActivity`. This means that you have a variety of bugs.

First, you need to be using `android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider`, not `android.widget.ShareActionProvider`.

Second, `android:showAsAction` and `android:actionProviderClass` need to be switched to `app:showAsAction` and `app:actionProviderClass`, as shown in [the documentation for `android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/ShareActionProvider.html). You will also need to add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` to your root `<menu>` element.

Third, use `MenuItemCompat` to get the `ShareActionProvider` in your code, after changing the import to be `android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider`.

[This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AppCompat/Share) demonstrates using `appcompat-v7` and its edition of `ShareActionProvider`. My menu resource is:

```
  <item
    android:id="@+id/share"
    android:title="Share!"
    app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```

and the Java code uses `MenuItemCompat`:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2012 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain   a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    https://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.sap;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    ShareActionProvider.OnShareTargetSelectedListener, TextWatcher {
  private ShareActionProvider share=null;
  private Intent shareIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  private EditText editor=null;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    editor=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editor);
    editor.addTextChangedListener(this);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.actions, menu);

    MenuItem item=menu.findItem(R.id.share);

    share=(ShareActionProvider)MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(item);
    share.setOnShareTargetSelectedListener(this);

    return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onShareTargetSelected(ShareActionProvider source,
                                       Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(this, intent.getComponent().toString(),
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    return(false);
  }

  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, s.toString());
    share.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
  }

  @Override
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                int after) {
    // ignored
  }

  @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                            int count) {
    // ignored
  }
}
</menu>
```