# Share Button in the actionbar is not working after publishing

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a share button in my app, it works fine with debug and release build but after publishing the same build on the PlayStore, the share button is not working. The button is visible in the actionbar but the share function is not working.

**share_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
        android:title="@string/share"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"/>
</menu>
```

**Main.java**

```
private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.share_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_item_share:
            Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i.setType("text/plain");
            String shareBodyText = getString(R.string.share_app);
            i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Share this App");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBodyText);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share this App"));
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check log. What is the error or Exception ?

Comment: check weather sharing app is available or not! code seems perfect

Comment: Please take a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36900815/share-button-not-working-on-app